# finding order in a group

Tags: group-theory

In a group if two elements commute with each other and their orders are relatively prime, then how to show that the order of their product is equal to the product of their orders?
     i.e, $o(ab) = o(a)  o(b)$ , where $a$ and $b$ are the elements of a group.

Comment: Hint: if $1=(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ then $x:=a^n=b^{-n}$ is in the intersection $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle$ of two subgroups. What does Lagrange say about the order of that intersection?

Comment: I am also fairly sure that this question has been asked on our site earlier. Did you search?

Comment: yes, got your point... and i searched but  didn't get this question in your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $o(ab)=n$,$o(a)=m$ and $o(b)=k$.

First we show that $n \;| \;mk$.

Observe that $(ab)^{mk}=a^{mk}b^{mk}=(a^m)^k(b^k)^m=1.$ But $n=o(ab)$. Thus $n\;|\;mk$.

Second we show that $mk \; | \; n$.

For that refer to Jyrki Lahtonen's comment. As $(ab)^n=a^n b^n=1 \implies a^n=b^{-n}.$ Let $x=a^n=b^{-n}$. Then $x \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$. By Lagrange's theorem, $o(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle)\;|\;o(a)=m$ and $o(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle)\;|\;o(b)=k$. Thus $o(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle)\;|\;mk$. But since $\gcd(m,k)=1$, Thus $o(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle)=1 \implies a^n=b^{-n}=1. \implies a^n=1=b^n.$

As $m=o(a)$ and $k=o(b)$, we get $m|n$ and $k|n$. Since $\gcd(m,k)=1$, we have $mk\;|\;n.$

$\therefore n=mk$.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you know this identity
$$\text{gcd}(a,b) \text{lcm}(a,b)=ab$$
and this crucial fact:

**Lemma:** If $gh=hg$, then $|gh|$ divides $\text{lcm}(|g|,|h|)$.

**Proof:** Let $|g|=m$ and $|h|=n$. If $N$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$ then $g^N = h^N = e.$ Note, since the elements commute, we have
$$(gh)^N =  \underbrace{(gh) \dots (gh)}_\text{$N$-many}  = \underbrace{g \dots g h \dots h}_\text{$2N$-many} = e$$
which occurs for any common multiple of $m$ and $n$. In particular,
$$(gh)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=e$$
and thus we must have $|gh|$ divide $\text{lcm}(m,n)$. $\square$

Now returning to your problem:

> If $gh=hg$ and $\text{gcd}(|g|,|h|)=1$ then $|gh|=|g||h|$.

Note that, by the identity previously mentioned, we have
$$\text{lcm}(|g|,|h|)=\dfrac{|g||h|}{\text{gcd}(|g|,|h|)}=|g||h|$$
and due to the lemma,

$|gh|=\text{lcm}(|g|,|h|)\cdot k \qquad k \in \mathbb Z^+$

$\implies |gh|=|g||h|\cdot k$.

Can you show now that $k=1$?

Comment: yes, i think so. because g and h are relatively prime so taking a number other than 1 will contradict the given situation.